# I am trying to make an alert for the first instance a value is > or < another

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5

Im relatively new to coding and am trying to figure out how to tell Pine Script to take the first instance the macD line is > and < the signal line to make an alert. Currently it shows a label every candle it is.

Trying to make "long" false after the first iteration, until "short" is true. To make only one alert per cross over.

Thank You to those who help. Ill give who ever solves this problem 15 xrp.

```
long = macd > signal
short = macd < signal
alertcondition(long, "Macd Long open", "message")
alertcondition(short, "Macd short open", "message")
if(long)
    l = label.new(bar_index, high)
    label.set_text(l, "buy@\n" + str.tostring(close))
    label.set_color(l, color.green)
    label.set_yloc(l, yloc.belowbar)
    label.set_style(l, label.style_label_up)

if(short)
    l = label.new(bar_index, high)
    label.set_text(l, "sell@\n" + str.tostring(close))
    label.set_color(l, color.red)
    label.set_yloc(l, yloc.belowbar)
    label.set_style(l, label.style_label_down)
```

'''

Comment: Just making sure you are aware that alerts only trigger on realtime bars, and not on historical bars? You can read a bit more about alerts in this "Keep in mind" section [link](https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-docs/en/v4/essential/Alerts.html). Let me know if it helped or not!

Comment: Im trying to figure out how to set it so "Long" would be false after the first iteration until "short" is true and vice versa. So it would only lead to one alert per cross over.

Comment: If i understood your question, I think you can just use: `long = ta.crossover(macd, signal)` or `short = ta.crossunder(macd, signal)`

Comment: That works perfectly, Thank you. I did offer 15xrp for who ever gets it right, shoot me an xrp wallet address and tag(if required).

Answer (score 0):

You have to write the MACD calculation formula, so I create a list

> [**macdline**, **singalline**, **macdhist**] = **ta.macd**(close, 12, 26, 9)

The basic equation is:

```
fast_length = input.int(title="Fast Length", defval=12)
slow_length = input.int(title="Slow Length", defval=26)
signal_length = input.int(title="Signal Smoothing", minval = 1, maxval = 50, defval = 9)

// Calculating
fast_ma = ta.ema(fast_length)
slow_ma =ta.ema(slow_length)
macd = fast_ma - slow_ma
signal = ta.sma(macd, signal_length)
hist = macd - signal
plot(hist, title="Histogram")
plot(macd, title="MACD")
plot(signal, title="Signal")
```

I solved your code problem

```
//@version=5
indicator("My script", overlay=true)


[macdline, singalline, macdhist] = ta.macd(close, 12, 26, 9)

long = macdline > singalline
short = macdline < singalline

if(long)
    l = label.new(bar_index, high)
    label.set_text(l, "buy@\n" + str.tostring(close))
    label.set_color(l, color.green)
    label.set_yloc(l, yloc.belowbar)
    label.set_style(l, label.style_label_up)

if(short)
    l = label.new(bar_index, high)
    label.set_text(l, "sell@\n" + str.tostring(close))
    label.set_color(l, color.red)
    label.set_yloc(l, yloc.abovebar)
    label.set_style(l, label.style_label_down)
    
alertcondition(long, "Macd Long open", "message")
alertcondition(short, "Macd short open", "message")
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).